# Looping in array (php codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

The problem is looping in $t array on controller page
Any Solution?
Here's my code

Controller:

```
function save($id)
    {
        $i=0;
        $t = array(     
            for($i;$i<=34;$i++)
                'j'.$i => $this->input->post('j'.$i),
                'status' => $this->input->post('1') 
        );
        $this->mmeeting->save($id,$t);
        redirect('admin/meeting','refresh');    
    }
```

Model:

```
function save($t){
    $this->db->insert("meeting", $t);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

View:

```
<?       
$i=1;
foreach ($im as $row):
$i++;
 ?>
<input name="j.<? echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row['when'] ?">>       
<? endforeach; ?>
 <input type="submit" value="register" tabindex="7" />
```

Meeting table in database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meeting`
(
  `j1` date ,
  `j2` date ,
   ....
  `j34` date ,
  status int(1),
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with codeigniter, just php. The following is not valid:

```
$t = array(     
                        for($i;$i<=34;$i++)
                        'j'.$i => $this->input->post('j'.$i),
                        'status' => $this->input->post('1') 
        );
```

Use this instead:

```
$t = array('status' => $this->input->post('1'));     
for ($i; $i <= 34; $i++) {
    $t["j$i"] = $this->input->post("j$i");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you want

```
function save($id)
    {
        $i=0;
        $t = array();    
        for($i;$i<=34;$i++)
           $t["j$i"] = $this->input->post("j$i");
        $t['status'] => $this->input->post('1'); 

        $this->mmeeting->save($id,$t);
        redirect('admin/meeting','refresh');    
    }
```